# Django auto_now count results in a certain date

Tags: django, django-models

I want filter of all request done is done in a certain date

```
class Log(models.Model):
    request          = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at       = models.DateField(default=now, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.request
```

But I don't how to do it correctly compare both the created_at and the date today

```
quantity_of_requests = Log.objects.filter(created_at=now()).count()
```

The objective is to take the current of date and count how many logs was added until now. But I also want to keep track of the time the request made.

I tried with this function but it takes of the time and put to 0:

```
datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Edit:
I did by doing this:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    request          = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at       = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.request

quantity_of_requests = Log.objects.filter(created_at__contains=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).count()
```

I would like to know a better way to write this code

Answer (score 0):

Your `now` gets initated when your django process runs. To correctly get local time every time, either override save() to set it or use `auto_now=True` on DateField.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now

Comment: But there's way to compare a date like the auto_now with the logs and then count how many was logs were made on the current day?

Comment: Yes, it will still save the information in the DateTimeField. You query it just like any other django field.

Comment: I understand but would you count the logs of the same day with this function?